# Hide links in video description

Tags: css, adblock

Many YouTube creators add links to video descriptions to various resources that I would like to selectively hide. For example, what it looks like:

```
Instagram: https://www.instagram.com
Facebook: https://www.facebook.com
```

Can uBlock Origin or Adblock completely hide the line containing the link to Instagram?

I was inspired by the: has pseudo-class with which you can block elements if they contain certain text. Can this be used somehow?

Answer (score 0):

Add manually into "My filters"

```
www.youtube.com##[href*="www.instagram.com"]
```